# Clicks outside active window aren't registering ONLY for certain apps

Tags: windows-10, mouse, taskbar, window

I am running Windows 10 version 22H2. Let's say I have Firefox or Discord open. I want to switch to a different window in the taskbar, or un-maximize the Firefox/Discord window and click on something else. This works fine, as expected.

But for certain apps, including Steam and Task Manager, this does not work. I can hover on another window in the taskbar, it will even show me the preview, but any clicks (both left and right click) outside the active window simply do not register. Whether Steam/Task Manager is maximized or minimized, even if the active window is very tiny and in the middle of the screen (say, the Steam login page), it will never let me click outside it. The mouse will act normally otherwise - say, if my Steam is open and I hover over some text on my Firefox page in the background, my cursor will change to the text cursor - but my clicks do not register.

I have checked and the Always on Top option is disabled for these apps. I can't seem to predict which apps will have this issue and which won't, it seems to be completely random.

The only thing I can think of is that I installed PowerToys and may have accidentally enabled something with some of their tools, but the problem persists even when I exit PowerToys and reboot the system.

Does anyone know what my issue could be? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: This issue does not seem to occur in Safe Mode. However, I am still unable to find which application or setting is causing it.

Comment: This is not something that should happen. Something on your system is causing this. I have PowerToys installed myself and I don't experience this. Its possible you have another program installed and that PowerToys somehow affect that program's functions. For example a program to dim the area around an app.

Comment: The reason I thought it could be PowerToys related is due to the PowerToys "Always on Top" tool. In any case, it's not currently running and nor is any other program which I suspect could affect this. I'm completely flummoxed.